# get count of certain extension files from Android device

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to count certain extension files (pdf, txt, docx, pptx, xlsx) which are stored in Android device using getcontentresolver query and reading file by file.
However, I'm getting different results from both ways. count results are the following:

By Content Resolver Query:

- pdf 289
- txt 133
- docs 29
- pptx 21
- xlsx 9

By reading file by file

- pdf 289
- txt 134
- docs 151
- pptx 77
- xlsx 27

Here is Code 
By Content Resolver Query:

```
public static long getFilesCount() {
    long myCounter = 0;
    String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
    String pdfMimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
    String txtMimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("txt");
    String docMimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("docx");
    String pptxMimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pptx");
    String xlsxMimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("xlsx");
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{pdfMimeType, txtMimeType, docMimeType, pptxMimeType, xlsxMimeType};
    Cursor mCursor = App
            .getInstance()
            .getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver()
            .query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
                    , null, selectionMimeType, selectionArgs, null);

    if (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int aCount = 0;
        do {
            int id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID));
            String path = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA));
            String type = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE));

            if (path == null || type == null)
                continue;
            File file = new File(path);

            if (file.exists()) {
                if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                    myCounter++;
                }
            }

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    if (mCursor != null && !mCursor.isClosed()) {
        mCursor.close();
    }
    return myCounter;
}
```

`

By reading file by file
`

```
public static long filesCount() {
        long counter =  _loadFiles(predefineExtension(), new File(getFilesPath())));
        return counter;
    }

    public static String getFilesPath() {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

}

public static ArrayList<String> predefineExtension() {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("pdf");
        list.add("txt");
        list.add("docx");
        list.add("pptx");
        list.add("xlsx");

        return list;
}

private static long _loadFiles(ArrayList<String> selectedExtension, File directory) {
    long counter = 0;
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i] != null) {
                if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                  counter +=  _loadFiles(selectedExtension, files[i]);
                } else {
                    File file = files[i];
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < selectedExtension.size(); j++) {
                            String ext = selectedExtension.get(j);
                            if (file.getPath().endsWith("." + ext)) {
                                counter++;
                                break;
                            } // file match
                        } // selected file extension loop
                    } // file exist
                } //  file is not directory
            } // file is not null
        } // loop
    } // files array is not null

    return counter;
}
```

So, my question is why these both approaches have different results? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what your question is, exactly. Are you asking why the two approaches have different results?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I also mentioned that in question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my question is why these both approaches have different results?

They are unlikely to be identical.

- Not every file on external storage necessarily gets indexed by the `MediaStore`. This is particularly true of files that were recently put on external storage and files in dot-prefixed directories (e.g., `.stuff/`).
- `MediaStore` has access to content on removable storage that you may not have access to.

Note that your filesystem-based approach will not work on Android Q (by default) or Android R+ (for all apps). I am not certain about your `MediaStore` approach.